# How can i create DateTime field in Module (Vtlib Function) from my CRM vtiger 7

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I hope all of you are doing well.
How can i create DateTime field  in Module (Vtlib Function) from my CRM vtiger 7.

Answer (score 0):

By default Vtiger Does not have general UI for DateTime Fields.
you can create them separately. use the following code:

```
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$module = new Vtiger_Module();
$module->name = 'YourModuleName';
$module = $module->getInstance('YourModuleName');
if ($module) {
    $blocks = Vtiger_Block::getAllForModule($module);
    $block = $blocks[0];
    
    $field1 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field1->name = 'mydate';
    $field1->table = $module->basetable;
    $field1->label = 'My Date';
    $field1->column = 'mydate';
    $field1->columntype = 'date';
    $field1->uitype = 5;
    $field1->typeofdata = 'D~O';
    $block->addField($field1);
    
    $field2 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field2->name = 'mytime';
    $field2->table = $module->basetable;
    $field2->label = 'My Time';
    $field2->column = 'mytime';
    $field2->columntype = 'time';
    $field2->uitype = 2;
    $field2->typeofdata = 'T~O';
    $block->addField($field2);
    
    $field3 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field3->name = 'mydatetime';
    $field3->label = 'My Date Time without UI';
    $field3->table = $module->basetable;
    $field3->column = 'mydatetime';
    $field3->columntype = 'datetime';
    $field3->uitype = 70;
    $field3->typeofdata = 'DT~O';
    $block->addField($field3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Hamid, The code you shared is perfect Create time, date field. But, I want to be create one field for both.